# Remove a function after it's been triggered once

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, event-listener, jquery-cookie

Forgive me, my jQuery/javascript knowledge is still in learning mode.

I have an exit-intent modal that pops up on my page. I'm using the jQuery cookie plugin to make sure that it doesn't come up again for a while. This is all working correctly, with one exception. If it's triggered on a page, it will trigger again on that same page if you don't navigate away. So someone closes the modal, then scrolls around the page, then has the modal come up again if they mouse away.

My question is, how can I remove that function, or alter it, once it's triggered one time? I know that it would only apply on that one page, but I'm hopeful the cookie will take care of it after they navigate away.

Thoughts? Here's my code so far.

```
    // Exit intent
    function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
        }
        else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
        }
    }

    // Cookie Expires every 5 Days
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var visited = $.cookie('visited');
        if (visited == 'yes') {
            return false;
        } else {
            addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
              if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null ) {
                  $('#modal').fadeIn();
                  $('.modalmask').fadeIn();
              }
            });
        }
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 5, path: '/' });
    });

    // Closing the Popup Box
    $('.close_modal, .modalmask').click(function() {
      $('#modal').fadeOut();
      $('.modalmask').fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why don't you use its event handling methods instead of rolling your own?

Comment: You can then use the jQuery `.one()` method to automatically remove a handler after it has triggered once.

Comment: @Barmar Like I said, I'm learning. So much of this is borrowed code from all over. Mind helping me narrow it down?

Comment: `$(document).one("mouseout", function(evt) { ... })`

Comment: @Barmar Instead of document ready? Now it's not firing at all?

Comment: No, instead of `addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) { ... })`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, gotcha. But what about the addEvent function from the top of the code? Is that not being called anymore?

Comment: No, we're using jQuery instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210193/discussion-between-harlan-bowling-and-barmar).